# Kafka doesn't consume all produced data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a single instance of kafka installed on a VM with 8 cores and 32GB RAM.

I write to it (produce) from 10 different machines and consume from one machine, all of which are in the same network.

The size of the data that I produce is ~ 35MBit / s.

For some reason, most of the time I can't consume more than ~ 10MBit /s (for limited periods of time I do manage to consume all the produced data), even though the kafka AND the consumer servers are mostly idle (therefore I don't think it's a retention problem).

Could kafka be ignoring some of the produced data?

Some parameter values that might be useful for analysis:

```
num.network.threads=32
num.io.threads=16
message.max.bytes=2147483647
num.partitions=10
log.retention.ms=120000 (2 minutes)
```

Comment: Do you have acks=1 or all for your producer?

Comment: @dawsaw Not sure, is that a client side property? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yeah it's on the producer client. You need to have acks=all to guarantee the broker has seen the message. acks=1 guarantees one broker saw it, which probably is the best you can do in your case. Also the code for the producer should handle cases where no ack is received to alert you to missing data and/or retry the send.

Comment: @dawsaw I just checked, it's set to 'all'

Comment: Ok so one thing that might be useful to post is the logic for the producer around the send() call. Something has to be done with the Future provided by the send message otherwise messages can be silently ignored. Also it would be good to know what version of Kafka is being used on the server and on the client side.

Comment: @dawsaw Basically, the logic around the send() call makes sure that if the onCompletion callback returns with a non-null exception it either retries or crashes the thread (depends on the exception type).
Needless to say, the thread never crashes.
As for the versions, client is 0.10.2.1 and server is 0.10.1.0

Comment: Ok so if the broker is acknowledging the response then the retention idea still should be explored with the 2 minute retention time. If you increase this some do you get more reliability? Do you have any configuration overrides on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Your retention time is way too low. If your consumer ever falls further than 2 minutes behind any one of the 10 producers then the messages will be lost. Try 24 hours or at least as much as you have disk space to fill. The default retention period is 7 days. Keeping messages for a longer period will also help you debug if they are all getting into the topic successfully.

Comment: I tried to increase the retention time to 1 hour (~16GB of data) to no avail. After the hour has passed kafka started struggling. The same happened when I tried it earlier with 10 minute retention - it worked for 10 minutes and then started struggling.

Comment: So it sounds like your bottleneck appears only when Kafka is deleting expired messages. Is the log.cleanup.policy on the topic you are using compact or delete? What kind of storage are you using? Could you be exceeding the disk IO capacity when both deleting log segments and writing new ones at the same time. Your rates are not very high but if the disk is very slow then it could cause this problem.